# Expected result is not clear in case of list.append(list)

Tags: python, python-2.7

Currently the output of below append cannot be used for practical purpose, This jira is to get the expectation for a case in append.

```
>>> a=[1,2]
>>> a.append(a)
>>> a
[1, 2, [...]]
>>>
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen here, and what is wrong with what you get?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for.  Are you just trying to get the list "`[1,2,1,2]`" instead of the nested list "`[1, 2, [1,2] ]`"?  If so, a simple `a+a` will do it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thanks for the response, is there any Python documentation which explains this behaviour ? I understood the reason but I was expecting it to be [1,2,[1,2]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third element is the entire list (i.e. a[2] is a, or id(a[2]) == id(a)). Because a contains itself, printing it would go on infinitely (a[2][2][2][2][2]...[2] == a), so the string conversion just gives you the "[...]" output.

Comment: I did not know Python allowed a recursive list, nor that it had a special syntax for displaying it.

Comment: @MarkRansom it's not so much a recursive list as it is an eternal self-referential loop...

Answer (score 0):

The answer by [Craig Meier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53639645/5987) explains why you're getting the output you're seeing. To eliminate the problem, make a *copy* of the list when you append it. A slice is the easiest way of copying a list.

```
>>> a=[1,2]
>>> a.append(a[:])
>>> a
[1, 2, [1, 2]]
```